# How to pause or delay animation using JavaScript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the text animation I am doing: **http://jsfiddle.net/4DJe6/**

I want the animation to pause for a second so the user can read the full text in red once and then it should start:

Any suggestion how can I add a second pause??

Here is the code:
**HTML**

```
<div><span id="black">Waiting for the task!</span><span id="red">Waiting for the task!</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#black{
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:2em;
}
#red {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    left:0px;
    width:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:2em;
    color:red;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

html {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**JS**

```
var red = document.getElementById('red');
var black = document.getElementById('black');
red.style.width = "0px";
var animation = setInterval(function(){
    console.log(red.style.width);
    if(red.style.width == "288px")
    {  
     red.style.width = "0px";}

    red.style.width = parseInt(red.style.width,10)+1 +"px";},30);
```

Let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you looked at CSS animations and `animation-delay`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
var red = document.getElementById('red');
    red.style.width = "0px";
var black = document.getElementById('black');

// Add Var to Keep Track of Pause
var pauser = 0;

var animation = setInterval(function(){
    if(red.style.width == "288px"){
        pauser += 34; // Increase Pause

        // Pause is Greater Than 1s
        if (pauser >= 1000){
            red.style.width = "0px"; // Reset Animation
            pauser = 0; // Reset Pause
        }
    } else {
        red.style.width = parseInt(red.style.width,10)+1 +"px";
    }
}, 30);
```

Updated Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4DJe6/1/).

I Hope this helps!